# No module named unidecode

Tags: python, pip

I'm executing odoo inside a docker container.
Don't understand what is going on with unidecode:

```sh
# python --version
Python 2.7.16

# pip --version
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

# pip install unidecode
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): unidecode in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...

# python -c "from unidecode import unidecode"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named unidecode
```

Some things tried from comments:

```sh
# which python
/usr/local/bin/python

# ls -lah /usr/local/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root staff    7 May  9 12:13 /usr/local/bin/python -> python2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root staff   14 May  9 12:13 /usr/local/bin/python-config -> python2-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root staff    9 May  9 12:13 /usr/local/bin/python2 -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root staff   16 May  9 12:13 /usr/local/bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff 7.4M May  9 12:12 /usr/local/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff 1.7K May  9 12:13 /usr/local/bin/python2.7-config

# python -c "import sys; print(sys.__dict__['path'])"
['', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Also listed what dist-packages:

```sh
# ls -lah /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/    
total 180K
drwxrwsr-x 11 root staff 4.0K Oct 15 13:01 .
drwxrwsr-x 31 root staff  20K May  9 12:13 ..
drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff 4.0K Oct 15 13:01 Unidecode-1.1.1-py2.7.egg-info
-rw-r--r--  1 root staff  185 May  9 11:13 easy-install.pth
-rw-r--r--  1 root staff  126 May  9 12:14 easy_install.py
-rw-r--r--  1 root staff  315 May  9 12:14 easy_install.pyc
drwxr-sr-x  4 root staff 4.0K May  9 12:14 pkg_resources
drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff 4.0K May  9 12:13 psycogreen
drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff 4.0K Dec 12  2017 psycogreen-1.0.egg-info
drwxr-sr-x  5 root staff 4.0K May  9 12:14 setuptools
drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff 4.0K May  9 12:14 setuptools-41.0.1.dist-info
drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff 4.0K May  9 11:13 six-1.12.0.dist-info
-rw-r--r--  1 root staff  32K May  9 11:13 six.py
-rw-r--r--  1 root staff  33K May  9 12:13 six.pyc
-rw-r--r--  1 root staff  33K May  9 12:13 six.pyo
drwxr-sr-x  2 root staff  12K Oct 15 13:01 unidecode
```

`unidecode` folder is one I've made a `cp Unidecode-1.1.1-py2.7.egg-info unidecode` just to try some things...

Could anyone help me on this? What's wrong, how can I solve this dependency?

Comment: what does `which python` says?

Comment: Also, try `python -c "import sys; print(sys.__dict__['path'])"` to see if your dist-packages are included in the default `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: BTW your `pip` version is ancient

Comment: @norok2 :) it's the default docker container for odoo... ':) `which python` seems to be pointing to 2.7 version, which is the one needed by odoo...

Comment: @CaitLANJenner see edited answer, it seems to be there...

Comment: `pip install unidecode --upgrade`?

Comment: @Dan already tried and result is the same

Comment: Try a virtual environment?

Comment: It seems like `pip` is coming from `/usr/lib` while your Python is coming from `/usr/local/bin`. I do not think you are using the right `pip` for your `python`.

Comment: There is no `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` in your `sys.path` ? How did you install python ?

Comment: @DinkoPehar this is the default odoo docker image... Just to test if that works, how can I move the package to site-packages? Maye next step would be to open an issue to odoo docker image...

Comment: Can you edit `sys.path` ? You can add folder like `sys.path.extend("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/")` before importing `unidecode` module. (I'm not familiar with docker, sorry)

Comment: @Miquel Can I add it as a question so you can mark it as complete ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to you problem may be solved by adding `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` to `sys.path` using `sys.path.extend("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/")`. Extend it before you import `unidecode` module.